# How can i insert decoded json data using json string in php mysql database

Tags: php

I have this JSON string.

```
{"Challenges":[{"phoneNumber":"1234567809","name":"Test2 Test2"},{"phoneNumber":"1234567890","name":"Test1 Test1"},{"phoneNumber":"8733806964*","name":"Dennish Desouzs"}],"Message":[{"message":"testchallenge1"}],"Level":[{"level_name":"testchallenge1","level_design":"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022200000000000080002000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000002000000000000000000220000000000000000002000000000000000000020000060000000000000200000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","win_time":3,"play_no":1,"top_user_id":"45","no_challenge":0,"user_id":"45","win_no":1}]}
```

code is as below:

```
mysql_select_db("hello") or die('Cannot select Database');
mysql_select_db("hello") or die('Cannot select Database');
$string=$_GET['records'];
$arr=json_decode($string);
$levelArray=array();
foreach ($arr['Level'] as $key=>$value) 
{
    $levelArray[] = $arr->Level;
    print_r($levelArray);
    $j = 0 ;
    foreach($levelArray  as $levelItem)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO level(user_id,level_name,no_challenge,level_design,play_no,win_no,win_time,top_user_id)VALUES('".$levelArray[$j]->user_id."','".$levelArray[$j]->level_name.'","'.$levelArray[$j]->no_challenge.'","'.$levelArray[$j]->level_design.'","'.$levelArray[$j]->play_no.'","'.$levelArray[$j]->win_no.'","'.$levelArray[$j]->win_time.'","'.$levelArray[$j]->top_user_id."'");
    }

 }  

?>
```

Problem is that I cannot insert data in the database by getting the values and at first I have to get all the data from the above string and then level string have to insert level table and challenge record string array should be insert in challenge table so what I should do to get this above string output?

Comment: `json_decode` returns an **object** so `$arr['Level']` should be `$arr->Level`

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `$arr['Level']` to `$arr->Level` in your foreach.

```
$levelArray = array();
foreach ($arr->Level as $key => $value) 
{
    $levelArray[] = $arr->Level;
    $j = 0 ;
    foreach($levelArray  as $levelItem)
    {
        $values = $levelItem[$j];
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO level(user_id,level_name,no_challenge,level_design,play_no,win_no,win_time,top_user_id) VALUES('".$values->user_id."','".$values->level_name.'","'.$values->no_challenge.'","'.$values->level_design.'","'.$values->play_no.'","'.$values->win_no.'","'.$values->win_time.'","'.$values->top_user_id."'");
    }

 }
```

Comment: It still not working to insert data in the database.

Comment: It still not insert data in my table I am using this code

Comment: <?php
 error_reporting(0);
  $Connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Cannot connect to Database');
 
   mysql_select_db("hello") or die('Cannot select Database');
 $string=$_GET['records'];
my problem is that i get record from one string which i have to insert in different tables but level table data not inserted only value got not insert in database... if any other idea???

Answer (score 0):

Another answer is , if you're familiar with array you can set

```
json_decode($string , true);
```

this will make your data in array structure

so instead of using **$arr->level;** , you can access it like **$arr['level'];**